# Mapreduce for image classification

Tags: java, hadoop, image-processing, mapreduce

I have I am trying to write a mapreduce program to calculate the euclidean distance between a test image and my training set which calculation is between  block of pixels instead of individual pixels.

So for each block of test image I have to find the nearest RGB color in my training set. How can I write mapper and reducer for these lists or images?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Build a KD-tree from the training set and than for each row in your test image find the nearest RGB neighbor in the KD-tree.